# flurry, in-app purchases, google checkout in PHONEGAP

Tags: cordova, google-checkout, flurry, in-app

I want to know that can we use following things in Phonegap.
    ·         in-app purchase,
    ·         flurry,
    ·         Google Checkout and
    ·         Any other integrations.

We need the info for Android and iOS both.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't but interested into some answers as I'd like to build a plugin for this type of thing